# Inheritance vs Interfacing in OOP design

Tags: oop

*note: This question is about generic OOP design, NOT a specific language. All code included is a pseudocode mix of python, C++, and Java that's designed to be legible without necessarily being perfect.*

One of the central tenets of OOP design is coding for interfaces, not implementations. A useful trick we have is importing contracts into our object from elsewhere. So a List object can implement both the Prototype contract and the Iterator contract (using the GoF design pattern terminology) and also implement its own methods. This lets us do something like

```
Prototype objects[] = {List, Integer, Image}
Prototype other_objects[]
for item in objects:
    Append item.Clone() to other_objects
```

and use runtime dispatching to figure out which Clone method gets called.

In multiple-inheritance languages (such as C++), we simply inherit each of those:

```
List inherits Prototype, Iterator {
    ...
    //overriding Prototype
    Clone() {...}
    ...
    //Overriding Iterator
    First() {...}
    Next() {...}
    IsDone() {...}
    CurrentItem() {...}
    ...
}
```

Here we don't care if Prototype and Inheritance are pure interfaces or abstract classes, since we're using true inheritance.

With single-inheritance languages multiple interface languages (such as java) we have to say that our object IS A specific type of object, and then we can give it interfaces. We can still use dispatching since the compiler knows that the object uses a particular contract.

```
List(AbstractList) implements Prototype, Iterator {
    ...
    //implementing Prototype
    Clone() {...}
    ...
    //implementing Iterator
    First() {...}
    Next() {...}
    IsDone() {...}
    CurrentItem() {...}
    ...
}
```

What other interfacing options exist/are common in OOP today and throughout history? For example, if a language doesn't have multiple inheritance and we also can't implement interfaces, what techniques exist?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Answer adapted from Züllighoven's Object Oriented Construction Handbook*

One possible way that single-inheritance interfaceless classes can have this property is by using GoF's Adapter design pattern.

What this pattern says is that if we have some object `myObject` with a particular interface and some class `Client` that can't understand that interface, create an object in the middle that can convert between them.

Then for each Adapter we have, pass it an object by reference and it can keep a handle to the object it needs to adapt. In this way, the client can manipulate the Adapter object as if it was the underlying object without caring that it isn't.